# How do I pass an array of objects that contains a component to child component in React with Typescript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I need to make Accordion component reusable. In the future I should be able to add new object to the same array 'accordionProps' and pass it down to accordion.

Here I'm passing an array 'accordionProps' of objects down to  component. Prop types are defined in child component Accordion which matches my array content.

```
     const accordionProps = [
    {
      title: 'Active Orders',
      body: <OrderModule />,
    },
    {
      title: 'Drivers',
      body: <DriverModule />,
    },
  ];

  return (
    <DashboardWrapper>
      <Accordion title={title} body={body}/>
      <Map />
    </DashboardWrapper>
  );
};

export default Dashboard;
```

Still TypeScript throws an error:

> Type '{ accordionProps: { title: string; body: Element; }[]; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & accordionProps'.
> Property 'accordionProps' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & accordionProps'.

It doesn't work when I do pass props as {...accordionProps}  either.

Here is what my child component Accordion looks like:

```
import { Component } from 'react';

type accordionProps = [
  {
    title: string;
    body: Component;
  },
];

const Accordion = (props: accordionProps) => {
  return (
    <AccordionContainer>
      {props.map(section => (
        <div key={section.title}>
          <div>{section.title})</div>
          <div>{section.body}</div>
        </div>
      ))}
    </AccordionContainer>
  );
};

export default Accordion;
```

I can't figure why TS is not letting me do that.

Does anyone know if an abstraction like that is even possible in React?

Help is really appreciated.

[Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/ecstatic-jasper-2409j?file=/src/App.tsx)

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! [Please do not post images of your code.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) Instead add your code and errors as text to your question. This allows us to copy paste it as we explore options for answering you, as well as other benefits.

Comment: @Alex Wayne Thanks for the tip. Pardon me. First post in SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You declared your prop types as an array with one object in it:

```
type AccordionProps = [
  {
    title: string;
    body: Component;
  },
];
```

However, react props must be an object:

```
type AccordionProps = {
  title: string;
  body: Component;
},
```

---

Then, in order to render an array of items, you need to map over the array of props, rendering the component you want in each iteration of the loop.

For example, assuming you had:

```
  // declare an array of AccordionProps objects
  const accordionProps: AccordionProps[] = [
    {
      title: 'Active Orders',
      body: <OrderModule />,
    },
    {
      title: 'Drivers',
      body: <DriverModule />,
    },
  ];
```

Then you might render those like so:

```
<>
  { accordionProps.map(props => <Accordion {...props} />) }
</>
```

---

### Update from your complete example:

React components always take an object for props, never an array. One of those props may be an array, but the props as a whole must be an object. So `props.map` is never right.

So first, let's fix your `Accordion` component:

```
type AccordionSection = {
  title: string;
  body: ReactNode;
};

type AccordionProps = {
  sections: AccordionSection[];
};

const Accordion = (props: AccordionProps) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {props.sections.map((section) => (
        <div key={section.title}>
          <div>{section.title})</div>
          <div>{section.body}</div>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Here `props` is an object with a single property `sections`. `sections` is type to be an array of `AccordionSection` objects. That means you can iterate through those sections with `props.sections.map`.

Also note that I change the type of `body` from `Component` to `ReactNode`. `Component` is a type for renderable components, where `ReactNode` is the type for already rendered content. `function MyComponent() { return <></> }` is a component. `<MyComponent />` is a `ReactNode`.

Now when you call this component, you have to pass in the `sections` prop as an array of `AccordionSection` objects.

```
import Accordion, { AccordionSection } from "../Accordion";

export default function App() {
  const accordionSections: AccordionSection[] = [
    {
      title: "Active Orders",
      body: <OrderModule />
    },
    {
      title: "Drivers",
      body: <DriverModule />
    }
  ];

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Accordion sections={accordionSections} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

[Updated Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/ecstatic-jasper-2409j?file=/src/App.tsx)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Looks like TS doesn't like me assigning this type to array:

        const accordionProps: SomeRandomProps[]

it throws  ''SomeRandomProps' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here. Did you mean 'typeof SomeRandomProps'?ts(2749)'"

Also in render it prompts to add key.

{accordionProps.map(props => (
        <Accordion key={props.title} {...props} />
      ))}

When I do that it shows a warning: 'title' is missing in props validation'. by eslint. With all these warnings the build breaks

Comment: Btw, since we are mapping through in Parent component, do we remove these in Accordion itself?

const Accordion = (props: AccordionProps) => {
  return (
    <AccordionContainer>
      {props.map(section => (
        <div key={section.title}>
          <div>{section.title})</div>
          <div>{section.body}</div>
        </div>
      ))}
    </AccordionContainer>
  );
};

Comment: When I remove AccordionProps[] type from array in render it throws:

"Type '{ title: string; body: Element; key: string; }' is not assignable to type 'AccordionProps'.
  Types of property 'body' are incompatible.
    Type 'ReactElement<any, any>' is missing the following properties from type 'Component<{}, {}, any>': context, setState, forceUpdate, render, and 2 more."

Comment: I don't know what `SomeRandomProps` props is, but it would need to be a type to use it like that. It's hard to parse all this without an [working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). If you post one, like say on a http://codesandbox.io I can probably help you more.

Comment: Can you access this: https://codesandbox.io/s/elegant-platform-lo0h4?file=/src/App.tsx

In App.tsx render method it throws an error in render

Comment: Answer updated. Hopefully that works for you.

Comment: Did you  make changes in codesandbox? I see the same thing I wrote. Sorry

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/ecstatic-jasper-2409j?file=/src/App.tsx definitely should take you to the one I changed. Regardless, it's not much different than the what I posted in the question.

Comment: Thank you Alex. This is awesome! There is no error in VS code but in the browser there's one which refers to other components issues. So I'm unable to test your code until I resolve other issues. I believe it will work just fine though.

Comment: Glad I could help! Don't forget to accept the answers that helped you the most with the checkmark button, and please upvote them when you have enough reputation to do so.